# Proxy for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

Are there any built-in proxy settings in Google Chrome? I mean that when I want to set the proxy in it.  It just brings up the systems proxy settings...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will work only on a windows machine

Right Click on the Chrome shortcut
Go to Properties >> Shortcut Tab
Add `--proxy-server=proxy server:port` to the end of content in Target Section

Comment: google-chrome --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8118

Comment: it doesn't accept this entry to the target..

Answer (score 1):

The reason it brings up the 'system' settings is that it uses those settings by default.  Set those, and they're set for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Chrome Command Line Switches by adding --proxy-server=IP:PORT to Chrome shortcut or in run command or you can also Using Extension like SwitchySharp.

You can find all the step-by-step tutorial for all 3 ways here http://answer-mee.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-use-proxy-server-on-google-chrome.html

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome inherits IE proxy setting in default. Below guide will help all windows users to configure.

- **[Configuring Independent Proxy for Chrome!](http://www.geeklk.com/2011/02/494/)**